How can I get the horizontal spacing to look nicer in math mode when I multiply a vector by a matrix?
I am trying to type a letter with an arrow over it next to a vertically ruled array, but the arrow touches the vertical rule.
In my MWE,I use esvect and nicematrix because that is my situation at home. However, the situation persists with just a regular array, and becomes worse with \vec{}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect,nicematrix}
\begin{document} 
\[
\vv{\jmath}
\begin{NiceArray}{|c|}
    j
\end{NiceArray}
\]
\end{document}



Is there a more conventional way to do  this?

Do you really need a matrix? I'd say that |j| would be better.

It my actual document, it is a 3 by 2 determinant matrix @egreg.  I make it a 1X1 so the MWE would be smaller.

I see no problem with vmatrix.
If you insist in nicematrix (but I don't see why), use \, between the two objects.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}

\[
\vv{\jmath}
\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \end{vmatrix}
\]

\end{document}



Thank you. By the way, I am using nicematrix here because I also have [first-row] and [baseline=1].

@Jasper Avoid minimizing too much.

While I always appreciate egreg's expertise, I am inclined to mention that for sake of consistency with the spacing of the normal array environment, the margin parameter for NiceArray will produce the exact same spacing. For this reason, I decided to post this answer.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{esvect,nicematrix}
\begin{document} 
\[
\vv{\jmath}
\begin{NiceArray}[margin]{|c|}
    j
\end{NiceArray}
\]
\end{document}


